# Check the role of a user in a database

Tags: sql-server

So, the question is:
How can I set up a query to tell me if a certain user has a certain role in a database? 
I came up with this:

```
SELECT @sql = 'USE [' + @nameDB + '];'
EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql
if (select COUNT(*) from sys.database_principals princ left join sys.database_permissions perm on perm.grantee_principal_id = princ.principal_id where name = 'User') = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'USE [' + @nameDB + '];'
        EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql
        CREATE USER [User] FOR LOGIN [User]
        ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [User]
    END
```

I want to know if "User" is a db_datareader for a series of databases. If it's not, grant him the role. The problem is that the USE doesn't point me on the right database, but sticks on master, so the IF block is never executed. Any suggestions?

Comment: `USE` doesn't stick to master. The query where it applies though is the one contained in `@sql`

Comment: Why are you using `sp_sqlexec`? You should really be using `sp_executesql`. Also, if this is being used by an interface, `'USE [' + @nameDB + '];'` is far from safe from injection.

Comment: So I have to wrap everything in sql?

Comment: @meltigel no, you should use a three-part name to specify the database you want in your query, eg `myDB.sys.database_principals`

Comment: I can use variable @nameDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you the result you are after, **provided** the name of user is actually hard coded to `[User]`. If it isn't you'll need to further parametrise your query and quote the relevant object names:

```
DECLARE @nameDB sysname = N'YourDB';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@nameDB) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'IF (DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(N''User'') IS NULL) BEGIN' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'    CREATE USER [User] FOR LOGIN [User];' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [User];' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'END;';
PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

*Edit: `USER_ID` is deprecated, I should know better.*

Example of parametrised version for the User:

```
DECLARE @nameDB sysname = N'YourDB';
DECLARE @User sysname = N'User'
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@nameDB) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'IF (DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(@User) IS NULL BEGIN' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'    CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@User) + N' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@User) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(@User) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'END;';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@User sysname', @User = @User;
```

Comment: Missed a parenthesis out @meltigel .

Comment: Good to hear, @meltigel. Just remember to **properly** parametrise the query and quote dynamic object names *if* you aren't checking against the literal name `user`. **Do not** write something like `'...DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(N''' + @user + ''')...'`, as that will mean your query is wide open to injection. If this did solve the problem, please do mark it as the solution so that future readers know it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Will do right now... Since I'm learning sql server, can you please explain the functionality of all of those 'N's?

Comment: I'll add an example for you on a parametrise version to be safe then, @meltigel (give me a few minutes). The `N` is there as object names, in SQL Server, use the datatype `sysname` (which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)`). An `nvarchar` can store unicode characters, therefore, whenever I write dynamic SQL I always make sure to use an `nvarchar` literal string as well then ensure that there are no "unexpected" errors due to a unicode character. To declare a unicode string (`nvarchar`) in SQL Server, you have to prefix the string literal with an `N`, thus `N'unicode string'` and `'ANSI string'`.

Comment: *For, `sp_executesql`, however, both the first parameters require an `nvarchar`, so `'@User sysname'` instead of `N'@User sysname'` would actually generate an error.*